# Alpine Linux - can't build libtorrent, missing linux/netlink.h

Tags: compiling, make, alpine-linux, rtorrent

I'm trying to compile [libtorrent](https://github.com/rakshasa/libtorrent) on Alpine Linux.
`autogen` and `configure` work fine but after invoking `make` it fails with the following message:

```
local_addr.cc:45:10: fatal error: linux/netlink.h: No such file or directory
```

I looked in `/usr/include` and found only `netlink/netlink.h`. However the next include in the source file is `rtnetlink.h` which doesn't exist.
Is this due to a missing dependency or perhaps a problem related to glibc/musl? How do you build libtorrent/rtorrent under Alpine Linux?
I am aware there is an rtorrent package for Alpine but would rather prefer to build it myself, so I can customize the build options.

These are the packages I installed prior to my build attempt:

- autoconf
- automake
- libtool
- pkgconfig
- ncurses-dev
- zlib-dev
- libsigc++-dev
- libcurl
- curl-dev
- libnl-dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [appears](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=netlink.h&path=&name=linux-headers&branch=edge&repo=main&arch=x86_64) that the linux-headers package contains `netlink.h`, so install it:

```
apk add --update linux-headers
```